# Auto detect user environment using php

Tags: php, ios-simulator, wap

I wants to detect if my website accessed through mobile devices , IPad , Tabs or thorugh common web access platform i.e. desktop or laptop.

According to access platform i wants to set different layout and css for each environment.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: RTLM http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: If you need more information about the browser than give you `get_browser()` see the javascript library [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) _Modernizr is a JavaScript library that detects HTML5 and CSS3 features in the user’s browser._ And search information about `Responsive (Web) Design` ([Responsive Web Design: What It Is and How To Use It](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [Mobile_Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/) to do it and it works pretty good for me!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [get_browser](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) command. It will return an array of all kinds of goodies about the user agent .

This relies on a file on the system called browscap.ini if your system's package manager doesn't support automatic update of this file  then [here](http://israelwebdev.wordpress.com/2010/10/19/automatically-update-your-php_browscap-ini/) is a resource that will help you keep your browscap.ini file up to date.